# Custom ConfigurationProvider in ASP.NET Core ADO.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Although there are lots of examples of EF with a custom configuration provider, I am struggling to find any samples that use ADO.net.

Set up :-

We have .net core API application, global configuration is stored in a MSSQL database as a typical key value pair.
We have created the appropriate layers to retrieve this data, however, using a custom configuration provider, how can we add these configuration to Options so we can access them through the site?

Obviously, trying to set this up in program.cs none of the connection strings have been set up due to these being in startup.cs

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-using-asp-net-core-and-ado-net/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion.  However, this is just for simply getting data,  Im looking for a customer configuration provider in .net core which can get the data, and link it IOptions

Comment: Some examples here: https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Configuration it's quite easy to write a simple (no reload) custom provider. It gets trickier if you want to support data reload/refresh

Comment: Here's one that uses SQL server (no entity framework) and supports reload: blog: https://mousavi310.github.io/posts/a-refreshable-sql-server-configuration-provider-for-net-core/ github: https://github.com/Mousavi310/Mousavi.Extensions.Configuration.SqlServer

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 perfect!  this has really helped.  did you want to make this an answer and i will mark it as accepted?